# Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I've started to make a memory game but I have a problem:

```
let card = [];

function makeCards() {

  let cardSymbol = [];

  const scorePan = document.querySelector('section');

  scorePan.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<ul class="deck"></ul>');

  const cardDeck = document.querySelector('.deck');


  for (let i = 1; i < 17; i++) {

    card[i] = document.createElement('li');

    card[i].setAttribute('class', 'card');

    cardSymbol[i] = document.createElement('i');

    cardSymbol[i].setAttribute('class', `fa fa-${symbols[i]}`);

    card[i].appendChild(cardSymbol[i]);

    cardDeck.appendChild(card[i]);
  }


}

makeCards();
```

So int the array card I've  stored all the cards, and added the cards in function makeCards , the problem is I want to add an Event Listener in  another function  to every single card, but if I iterate over the elements
 with a for loop and I console.log() every element it shows me undefined, and this happens either I write the loop in a function or outside any function, but If I console.log(card) ; it shows me an array that contains all the elements of the array. Why I can't loop over them since I have an array?? Or should I add the eventListerns to elements when I create them in the function makeCards?????

Comment: Can you share the function where you are trying to bind event listners ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a live event listener. If you are using jQuery you can use [this](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

or if you are using native js, you can implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106329/implementing-jquerys-live-binder-with-native-javascript)

Comment: `native js` as in pure unadulterated JS without any plugins, tools or libraries.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022007/what-is-native-javascript

Answer (score 0):

We can set one element that is a common ancestor to **all *card* elements** to listen for a `"click" event` occuring on it and/or its descendants. This is possible because of how an event bubbles. For details on this procedure read this article about **[Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)**.

The following Demo creates 2 arrays of matched FA classes and shuffles them. The ancestor element is created as *`deck`* and its descendant elements are *`card`*, and *`face`* elements which are created on each iteration of a `for` loop. Only the basic function of *flipping* is provided for each *`card/face`*, the logic for matching is beyond the scope of the OP question and requires a separate question to be posted.

### Demo

**Details are commented in Demo**

```js
/* Hardcode FA classes in symbol array
== Clone symbol array
== Use shuffle() function on both arrays
== Merge both arrays into faces array
*/
var symbol = ['fa-pied-piper-alt', 'fa-heart', 'fa-star', 'fa-star-o', 'fa-paw', 'fa-leaf', 'fa-cube', 'fa-cubes', 'fa-rebel', 'fa-empire'];
var match = symbol.slice(0);
var topCut = shuffle(symbol);
var bottomCut = shuffle(match);
var faces = topCut.concat(bottomCut);

// Create and reference parent element
var stack = document.createElement('main');
stack.id = 'deck';

// for each loop...
for (let c = 0; c < match.length * 2; c++) {

  // Create a card element and add attributes
  var card = document.createElement('a');
  card.href = '#/';
  card.classList.add.apply(card.classList, ['card', 'cover']);

  /* Create a face element and add attributes
  || Note: each face is assigned a FA icon but not .fa class
  */
  var face = document.createElement('i');
  face.classList.add('face');
  face.classList.add(faces[c]);

  // Add each face to a card and each card to the deck (stack)
  card.appendChild(face);
  stack.appendChild(card);
}

// When complete, add deck to DOM
document.body.appendChild(stack);

// Reference deck
var deck = document.getElementById('deck');

/* Register deck to click event
|| When deck and/or its descendant elements are clicked...
|| invoke callback function flip()
*/
deck.addEventListener('click', flip, false);

// Pass Event Object
function flip(event) {

  // Prevent <a> from jumping to a location
  event.preventDefault();

  /* event.target: origin of click event (clicked element)
  || event.currentTarget: element that listens for click (#deck)
  || if the clicked element is NOT #deck...
  */
  if (event.target !== event.currentTarget) {

    //...and if that clicked element is an <a>...
    if (event.target.tagName === "A") {

      /* toggle clicked <a> class .cover and 
      || its child <i> class .fa on/off
      */
      event.target.classList.toggle('cover');
      var trump = event.target.firstElementChild;
      trump.classList.toggle('fa');
    }
  }
}


// Utility function uses Fisher-Yates algorithm to shuffle arrays
function shuffle(array) {
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  var temp = null;
  for (i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 1) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
    temp = array[i]
    array[i] = array[j]
    array[j] = temp
  }
  return array;
}
```

```css
#deck {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 5px inset brown;
  background: green;
}

.card {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px
}

.face {
  transform: translateY(11px);
  pointer-events: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.cover {
  color: transparent;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```